# Why doesn't my browser react to my JavaScript with the "click" function?

Tags: javascript, html

I am not able to make the images in my browser change when I press the mouse on them. I have really been trying to find an answer to this, but have not... so

I've tried to change the variables and so to ".jpg" and tried taking it away as well.

```js
var stockholm = document.getElementById("stockholm.jpg");
var tokyo = document.getElementById("tokyo.jpg");
var newyork = document.getElementById("newyork.jpg");

stockholm.addEventListener("click", function() {
  stockholm.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  tokyo.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  newyork.style.backgroundColor = "white";
});

tokyo.addEventListener("click", function() {
  stockholm.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  tokyo.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  newyork.style.backgroundColor = "white";
});
newyork.addEventListener("click", function() {
  stockholm.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  tokyo.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  newyork.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
});
var stockholm = 1;
var stockholm = document.getElementById("stockholm");
stockholm.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (nr % 3 == 0) stockholm.src = "tokyo.jpg";
  else if (nr % 3 == 1) stockholm.src = "newyork.jpg";
  else stockholm.src = "stockholm.jpg";
  nr++;
});
```

I expected there to be a change in images in the browser when pressing on them with the mouse.

Comment: `.jpg`s are not elements, thus your document.getElementById calls are all returning null. You should add ids to your img tags and get them by ID

Answer (score 1):

What @controlAltDel said is correct also, and you should listen to his advice.

Set the width and height of the image, because you are changing the background **color**! How are you going to see the background change with an image ontop of it (if you are using an image).

```js
var stockholm = document.getElementById("stockholm");
stockholm.addEventListener('click', function() {
  stockholm.style.background = 'red'
})
```

```html
<!-- Use stockholm instead of stockholm.jpg -->
<img src="" id="stockholm" width="500px" height="500px"/>
<!-- <div id="stockholm" width="500px" height="500px"> -->
<!-- <img src="" id="stockholm" width="500px" height="500px"/> -->
```